# Test with userEvent.keyboard() does not pass, however it works in the browser

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have the following test written with React Testing library. When I check it out in the browser, it works. However, here it doesn't work. What can be wrong?

```js
  it('Calls search callback on enter key press', () => {
    const mockSearchCallback = jest.fn();

    render(<Header onSearch={mockSearchCallback} />);

    userEvent.type(screen.getByRole('textbox'), 'testquery');

    userEvent.keyboard('{Enter}');

    expect(mockSearchCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

However, it fails.
`Header` acts almost like a wrapper, all the logic is contained in Search.
Here's the code

```
export default function Search({ onSearch }: SearchProps) {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit: React.FormEventHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (query) {
      onSearch(query);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form className="c-search" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        className="c-search__input"
        value={query}
        onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
        name="query"
        autoComplete="off"
      ></input>
    </form>
  );
}
```

UPD
It works with userEvent 13, but it doesn't with 14. Why?

Comment: did you manage to fix above issue?

Comment: @AshishPatil the only way to resolve it is downgrade user event version to 13.5.0. However, with the latest one it doesn't work

Comment: Can you also add your `Header` code here?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like an issue with `keyboard` for version 14.
I really dont know why this occuring but i will try to look depper into this later or even open a issue on `testing-library/user-event` github.

But for now, you can accomplish this test with this:

```js
it("Calls userEvent.type", async () => {
    const mockSearchCallback = jest.fn();

    render(<Header onSearch={mockSearchCallback} />);

    const inputEl = screen.getByRole("textbox");

    await userEvent.type(inputEl, "testquery{enter}");

    expect(inputEl).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(inputEl).toHaveValue("testquery");

    expect(mockSearchCallback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

So, i just call `{enter}` from `type` event.

You can check an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-userevent-input-test-nj5do6) -> Just click on Tests Tab.